# Return value in Future dart/flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Why the return value is always null ?

```
 _repository.addUpdateWorkOrder(workOrder).listen((ref) {
    image.id = ref.documentID;
    _repository
        .getImageDownloadUrl(ref.documentID, image.imagePath)
        .then((val) {
      print('The value of the input is: $val');
    });
  });
```

**repository**

```
@override
  Future<List<String>> getImageDownloadUrl(
      String id, List<Asset> imagePath) async {
    Future.wait(imagePath.map((Asset asset) async {
      ByteData byteData = await asset.requestOriginal();
      List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

      var dateTime = new DateTime.now();
      final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('images/' + id + '/' + dateTime.toString() + ' .jpg');

      return firebaseStorageRef.putData(imageData).onComplete.then(
          (uploadTask) =>
              uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => url.toString()));
    }));
  }
```

**Output**

> I/flutter (22901): The value of the input is: null

Comment: is `uploadTask` also null?

Comment: @PeterHaddad No. When I debug, I can see there are value on the url.

Comment: @PeterHaddad when I debug, it will run `print('The value of the input is: $val');` first, then only run `getImageDownloadUrl` method...

Comment: You can't return values from `then` methods, you should use `await` instead and assign the result in new variable then use it again. All I am talking about codes in `getImageDownloadUrl` function.

Comment: @ShadyBoshra I have edited my post. How should I modified the code?

Comment: @JohnJoe, please check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ShadyBoshra2012/3e224077febf89db1f2513325a29cf57) was coded for you, and tell me if it worked or what happened ?

Comment: @ShadyBoshra I get `The value of the input is: []`.

Comment: I updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/ShadyBoshra2012/3e224077febf89db1f2513325a29cf57) now, I changed map to work with for in loop, may it work better !

Comment: Happy to hear that, I will make it as an answer now, please mark it as it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198817/discussion-between-john-joe-and-shady-boshra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we talking in comments on question, we finally reach to a solution as we edit the `getImageDownloadUrl` function as in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ShadyBoshra2012/3e224077febf89db1f2513325a29cf57).

and here the code below

```
@override
Future<List<String>> getImageDownloadUrl(
    String id, List<Asset> imagePath) async {

  // Variable to hold the list of urls. 
  // Also I think you need only one String not List.
  List<String> list = List<String>();

  for (Asset asset in imagePath) { 

    ByteData byteData = await asset.requestOriginal();
    List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    var dateTime = new DateTime.now();
    final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('images/' + id + '/' + dateTime.toString() + ' .jpg');

    // Using await to hold the value that result.
    var uploadTask = await firebaseStorageRef.putData(imageData).onComplete;
    String url = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();

    // Add the url to list
    list.add(url);
  }

  return list;
}
```